# hot to update a database in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to update my database with new information, but i don't know how.

here's is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

listofplayers = [['player1', 5,1,300,100],['player2', 10,5,650,150],['player3', 17,6,1100,1050]]
listofplayers2 = [['player1', 105,101,10300,10100],['player11', 1010,105,10650,10150],['player23', 1017,106,101100,101050]]


dictdataframe = {
    'player': [],
    'win': [],
    'loss': [],
    'moneywin': [],
    'moneyloss': []
    }


for i in listofplayers:
    y = 0
    for k in dictdataframe.keys():
        dictdataframe[k].append(i[y])
        y +=1

db = pd.DataFrame(dictdataframe)
```

my output should be :

```
index,player,win,loss,moneywin,moneylost,
0,'player1', 105,101,10300,10100,
1,'player2', 10,5,650,150,
2,'player3', 17,6,1100,1050,
3,'player11', 1010,105,10650,10150,
4,'player23', 1017,106,101100,101050
```

i've spent all day on the web, but i never found what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Whoops, I missed the double `player1`! You are right, that is a much more difficult question. The best way I have found is to create two data frames, index them by `player` and call `combine_first`. Note that for this, you would call `df1.combine_first(df2)` if you want the values in df1 to supersede df2. If you wanted to set your own rules, you could use `combine`, as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html). Sorry for that! Below is the code:

```
add_to_dict(listofplayers,dictdataframe1)
add_to_dict(listofplayers2,dictdataframe2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictdataframe1).set_index('player')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictdataframe2).set_index('player')

a = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

We are using the `add_to_dict` function from below. Now our output is

```
           win  loss  moneywin  moneyloss
player                                   
player1    105   101     10300      10100
player11  1010   105     10650      10150
player2     10     5       650        150
player23  1017   106    101100     101050
player3     17     6      1100       1050
```

---

### Original Answer

There is no need for a double for loop. You were on the right track with `dictdataframe`. Instead of going too fancy with multiple loops, you can just loop through the elements and append them to that! Then all you need to  do is send to a data frame with the built in pandas method.

```
import pandas as pd

listofplayers = [['player1', 5,1,300,100],['player2', 10,5,650,150],['player3', 17,6,1100,1050]]
listofplayers2 = [['player1', 105,101,10300,10100],['player11', 1010,105,10650,10150],['player23', 1017,106,101100,101050]]

dictdataframe = {
    'player': [],
    'win': [],
    'loss': [],
    'moneywin': [],
    'moneyloss': []
    }


for x in listofplayers:
    dictdataframe['player'].append(x[0])
    dictdataframe['win'].append(x[1])
    dictdataframe['loss'].append(x[2])
    dictdataframe['moneywin'].append(x[3])
    dictdataframe['moneyloss'].append(x[4])

for x in listofplayers2:
    dictdataframe['player'].append(x[0])
    dictdataframe['win'].append(x[1])
    dictdataframe['loss'].append(x[2])
    dictdataframe['moneywin'].append(x[3])
    dictdataframe['moneyloss'].append(x[4])


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictdataframe)
```

This gives us

```
     player   win  loss  moneywin  moneyloss
0   player1     5     1       300        100
1   player2    10     5       650        150
2   player3    17     6      1100       1050
3   player1   105   101     10300      10100
4  player11  1010   105     10650      10150
5  player23  1017   106    101100     101050
```

This is pretty verbose though. We can abstract the loop away with a function, like so:

```
def add_to_dict(listplayers,dictionary):
    for x in listplayers:
        dictionary['player'].append(x[0])
        dictionary['win'].append(x[1])
        dictionary['loss'].append(x[2])
        dictionary['moneywin'].append(x[3])
        dictionary['moneyloss'].append(x[4])
    
    return None #we are editing the input dictionary.
```

Now we can just call the function on all of our lists and turn it into a data frame!

```
add_to_dict(listofplayers,dictdataframe)
add_to_dict(listofplayers,dictdataframe)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictdataframe)
```

This gives us the same output. If you REALLY wanna expedite it, you can make the function take in a list of `listofplayers` and spit out the data frame, but I will leave that as an exercise to you.

Comment: thanks but the player1 in listofplayers2 should overwrite the player1 in the dataframe. How can i make that happen as well?

Comment: @solarchick Apologies I missed that on the first go. I just updated my answer to reflect that, but the basic gist is that you should make them both into their own data frames, and then use `combine_first`, passing the data frame you want to take priority first. See my code above!